# Creating a log file

Tags: 14.04

I want to create a log file which contains PIDs of processes, their PPIDs,
Time stamps etc.
I have looked up into /var/log/ directory but haven't found anything useful.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `ps` command - an exhaustive list of options is beyond the scope of this site (see `man ps` for a complete description of its usage), but you can either use one of the 'standard' output formats such as (UNIX form)

```
ps -ef > my.log
```

or (BSD form)

```
ps aux > my.log
```

or choose individual fields for example

```
ps -eo pid,ppid,time,cmd > my.log
```

You may also find the `pstree` command (available from the `psmisc` package) useful.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. But 'ps' gives info about only current running processes.  I want info of certain period.

Comment: @user2447587 your question says you want to *create* a log -that involves storing information about current processes. I don't think you're going to find an *existing* log of such processes.